# How can I plot the relationship between `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` for a fixed value of `Petal.Length` and by `Species`?

Tags: r, ggplot2, mixed-models

I am running LME and I want to plot the relationship between my response variable and one of my predictors keeping constant the other predictor and by `ID` (considered as random factor).

Similarly, using `iris` dataframe example, it would correspond to this:

```
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)

df <- iris[,c("Sepal.Length","Sepal.Width","Petal.Length","Species")]

mod <-nlme::lme(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width * Petal.Length, random= ~ 1|Species, data = df,method="REML")
```

Where, as you can see, `species` is used as random factor. In this example, what I would like to plot is the linear relationship between `Sepal.Length` and `Sepal.Width` keeping constant `Petal.Length` and by `species`.

I have tried this:

```
Plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.7,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(mod, Petal.Length=mean(iris$Petal.Length)), group=Species), size=2.1)
Plot
```

[image]

However, the plot is the same than if I do this:

```
Plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.7,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(mod), group=Species), size=2.1)
Plot
```

So, I am not keeping constant `Petal.Length`. I also know that I am not keeping constant `Petal.Length` because I do not get a straight line for each species. That is, the incorportaion of `Petal.Length` is what made to the lines to be irregular, because when I do not consider `Petal.Length` in my model, I get this:

```
mod.b <-nlme::lme(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, random= ~ 1|Species, data = df,method="REML")

Plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) + 
  geom_point(size=1.7,alpha=0.6) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(mod.b), group=Species), size=2.1)
Plot
```

[image]

So, does anyone know how to do to keep one predictor (`Petal.Length`) constant when plotting linear predictions for an `LME` model by random factor?

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
newdf <- df
newdf$Petal.Length <- ave(newdf$Petal.Length, newdf$Species)

ggplot(df, aes(x=Sepal.Width, y=Sepal.Length, colour=Species)) + 
 geom_point(size=1.7,alpha=0.6) +
 geom_line(aes(y=predict(mod, newdf), group=Species), size=2.1)
```

[image]

NOTES:

- You were using the `predict` function in the wrong way. You need to add a whole new set of data, not just one column. Also, the way you were writing the new column was wrong because you were actually providing the `predict` function with an argument called `Petal.Length` which was falling into `...`, hence ignored.
- I calculated the average for each group with `ave`, otherwise your results wouldn't make sense. If you try to plot the graph by calculating the average of `Petal.Length` in this way `newiris$Petal.Length <- mean(newiris$Petal.Length)`, you will see what I mean.

---

When you write:

```
ave(newdf$Petal.Length, newdf$Species)
```

`ave` calculates the mean of `newdf$Petal.Length` for each group defined by `newdf$Species`

Comment: Thanks for your time @Edo, could you explain what `ave()` does and why my code did not work to understand where was the mistake? Also, I see that you create a dataframe called `newiris` but in the plot you call to the dataframe `df`, is it right?

Comment: I was still editing my answer :) it should be over now. Have a look. I added more details

Comment: Thanks for your updated reply @Edo. One last think. In my real case, I am interested in used different values for what here would be `Petal.Length`. Maybe here it does not take too much sense, but in my real case it does. Do you know how could I do to specify an specific value for `Petal.Length` different for the average?

Comment: You mean one different value for each group?

Comment: try `case_when` from the `dplyr` package

Comment: Thanks @Edo for your time :). I mean that I am interested in knowing how `Sepal.Length` varies as a function of `Sepal.Width` while keeping constant `Petal.Length`. Here it might have no sense to keep the same `Petal.Length` for different species, but in my real case it does. I want to plot the relationship `Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width` while, for example, `Petal.Length=1`, independently of the species.

Comment: Well, then just force `newiris$Petal.Length <- 1` and ignore `ave` :)

Comment: However, I have seen that `newdf$Petal.Length <- mean(newdf$Petal.Length)` works in this sense. Right? So I guess that what I should do is simply `newdf$Petal.Length <- 1`, and then I would be plotting the `Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width` when `Petal.Length` is `1` for different species. And just a note, if I use a different `Petal.Length` for different species, from a mathematical point of view, I am not observing only the effect of `Sepal.Width` on `Sepal.Length`, this effect is mixed with `Petal.Length` since it has a different value for each species.

Comment: In fact, in this case, I forced the model to have the same slope for different species, something that I don't see when I use a different `Petal.Length` for different `species`.